# How should I return a class based on the parameter class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class

So I have a function that takes in two vectors (a class) and returns a vector that is the dot product of the two vectors. I also have a ray class (that extends vector) for which I would like to return the same thing except as a ray instead of a vector. Is there anyway to do this without writing a seperate function, as the calculations done are identical?

EDIT: Code looks like this:

```
function crossProduct(vector1,vector2){
    cross_product_results = vector1[2]*vector2[0]-vector1[0]*vector2[2], vector1[0]+.....;
    return new Vector(cross_product_results)
}
```

but if I input a ray, I want it to do something along the lines of

```
return new Ray(cross_product_results)
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I think you might want to consider breaking your question down and adding some specifics. It too hard to help as is...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function crossProduct(value1, value2){
    cross_product_results = value1[2]*value2[0]-value1[0]*value2[2], value1[0]+.....;

    //return new Vector(cross_product_results)

    if (value1 instanceof Ray)
      return new Ray(cross_product_results);

    if (value1 instanceof Vector)
      return new Vector(cross_product_results);
}
```

The approach above assumes that:

1. The values of your arguments are created using something like `new Vector(...)` or `new Ray(...)`.
2. Both arguments are always of the same type.

**Note**

One detail is that we have to check for `Ray` instance before `Vector` instance because `Ray` is extended from `Vector`. Therefore values of `Ray` are also instanceof `Vector`, but values of `Vector` are not instanceof `Ray`.

```js
class Vector {}
class Ray extends Vector {};

const vector = new Vector();
const ray = new Ray();

console.log(vector instanceof Ray);
console.log(vector instanceof Vector);

console.log(ray instanceof Ray);
console.log(ray instanceof Vector);
```